# How to create custom time zone in python?

Tags: python

I want to create a Eastern European Time zone use US daylight saving time rules.

Here is what I have try:

```py
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime, timezone
import pytz
from backports.zoneinfo import ZoneInfo


class eastern_eur(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt: datetime):
        return timedelta(hours=2) + self.dst(dt)
    def dst(self, dt: datetime):
        dt = dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo("US/Eastern"))
        return dt.dst()

START = datetime(2018, 11, 2, tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(eastern_eur())
```

Got RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Is there any simpler way to achieve that without create a new class? Like is add offset to a ZoneInfo instance?